# Фамилия "Чапаев"

Tags: этимология

Подумалось, а от какого слова происходит фамилия знаменитого Чапаева?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот рассказ про происхождение фамилии "Чапаев", находящийся в музее Василия Ивановича Чапаева в городе Пугачёв Саратовской области, записанный по воспоминаниям Михаила Чапаева – брата легендарного начдива.

Дед Василия Ивановича – Степан Гаврилович в документах писался Гавриловым. 
В 1882 или 1883 году Степан Гаврилович с товарищами подрядились грузить брёвна. В артель к ним попросился босяк Веньяминов. Его приняли. Старшим в артели был Степан Гаврилович. Как старший он обычно выкрикивал товарищам по работе: 
-Чепай, чепай! (Цепай, цепай, что значит «бери, бери». «Ч» вместо «Ц»- особенность русского говора города Чебоксары. Там, например, говорят «чиган» вместо «цыган», «чапля» вместо «цапля», «чарапать» вместо «царапать» и т.д.) 
Когда кончили работу подрядчик не сразу отдал деньги за работу. Деньги должен был получить и раздать как старший Степан Гаврилович. Старик долго ходил за деньгами. Веньяминов бегал по пристани, искал Степана. Забыв его имя, он спрашивал всех: 
- Не видели ли грязевского (Грязево – другое название деревни Будайка) старика, красивого, кудрявого, всё говорит «чапай»? 
- Он, Чапай, не отдаст тебе денег, - подшучивали над Веньяминовым. Потом, когда дед получил заработанные деньги, он разыскал Веньяминова, отдал ему заработок, угостил его. 
А кличка «Чапай» так и осталась за Степаном. За потомками же закрепилось прозвище «Чапаевы», которое потом стало официальной фамилией.
(http://chapaev.ru/84/Proiskhozhdenie-familii-CHapaev/)

Comment: *<<«Ч» вместо «Ц»- особенность русского говора города Чебоксары.>>*

Спасибо, **olsa**, мне очень интересно было прочитать Ваш ответ.

Возможно, это какой-то старинный славянский говор? 
Потому что кое-то из перечисленного встречается и в украинском **литературном** языке.


цапля - *укр*. чапля

цеплять - чіпляти; цепляй - чіпляй.

Comment: Это особенность не "города Чебоксары", а огромного ареала северо- и среднерусских диалектов от Пскова до Перми. 
Не знаю, связано ли это с ураинским, возможно параллельные процессы.
Вот в отношении распрстранения его в Среднем Поволжье ничего не слышал, хотя Чебоксары в общем-то недалеко от мест классического "чокания".

В остальном история фамилии Чапаев этимологически верная.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к ответу behemothus

Answer (score -1):

Колонизация русскими новых обширных территорий происходила не только за счет перемещения потомственного русского населения, но и по "принципу домино" - за счет обрусения местного населения и последующей колонизации новыми уже русскими соседних земель. Отсюда и особенности местных говоров. Например у чувашей не было своих слов со звуком "Ц", соответственно первые обрусевшие чуваши вместо "Ц" произносили привычное им "Ч".
Насчет "Чепай" вместо "цепай" - выдумки. Чепай - это традиционное чувашское имя.